# How to access memcache on App Engine Nodejs Standard

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, memcached

How does one access memcache from the nodejs standard environment?

Comment: GCP is disaster for developing node.js app, many stuff is under developing and have no documentation, included memcache... though I finally choose to use python, but I found this https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/memcached/app.js once before. I think it is still helpful for you to get start.

Comment: I ended up writing a service in another language to access memcache

Comment: Yes, I came up to use python instead after suffering in nodejs.

Comment: Ah yes it's frustrating. At least AWS doesn't have those weird limitations. I mean why don't they just open access to the default GAE memcache service just like any other languages? I don't get why nodejs specifically can't access it...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The documentation apparently makes no reference to the App Engine memcache being available to the Node.JS standard environment, at least not at this time:

- there is no `Node.JS` language tab in the [Memcache Overview](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/memcache/) page(s)
- there is no `Caching Application Data` section (under which the memcache-related docs exist for the other languages) under `How-to Guides` in the left-side navigation bar for [Google App Engine Node.js Standard Environment Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/)

But there may be an alternative. From [APIs & Reference](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/apis):

> [image]

Which leads to [Node.js Packages](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/libraries), where I can see:

> [image]

Which leads to [Cloud Redis: Node.js Client](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/redis/0.1.x/).

This is inline with the suggestions from the [Memcache](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/migrating#memcache) section of the [Migrating Services from the Standard Environment to the Flexible Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/migrating) guides, the flexible environment having the same problem (except clearly documented):

> The Memcache service is currently not available for the App Engine
>   flexible environment

Comment: Thanks for the help! I have had a hard time with nodejs on App Engine so far in both flex and standard.

Comment: April/2019 and Google App Engine with NodeJS still do not support the AppEngine's memcache.

Comment: April/2020 and Still Google App Engine with nodeJs does not support the AppEngine's Free Memcache. But there are paid alternative available now with a name called MemoryStore service(Redis) for both standard via VPC and flex env. 

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/using-memorystore